# Is there a way to find the theme file in Wordpress using the name?

Tags: wordpress

In the wordpress admin dashboard, on the pages tab, when you edit the page, there's a section called "Page Attributes".  One of the options is "Templates", which opens a drop-down list of templates available.

Is it actually possible to find which template name corresponds to which file in the theme editor without looking through every single file in the theme editor?

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way to achieve this is, if you want to get the file name then you can add in the template name directly

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template (example_template.php) */ ?>
```

So you will see  the `Example Template (example_template.php)` in template dropdown